# Meteor update 0.6.4 -> 0.6.5 , mongo error

Tags: meteor

I updated meteor from 0.6.4.1 to 0.6.5. 
I have Centos 6.4. 
After update I run into this error when running meteor:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.
```

Can't start mongod

Even if I create a new project:

`meteor create newproj : cd newproj : meteor`

i have the same error.

I try meteor restart, nothing seems to work, any project **not updated to 0.6.5** is still working.

Anyone know what I'm babbling about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm also getting this error on Ubuntu. As mentioned, it's caused by mongo and mongod from ~/.meteor/tools/latest/mongodb/bin being compiled with an older version of glib.

You can replace the version of mongo  bundled by meteor with the version installed in your system:

```
cd ~/.meteor/tools/latest/mongodb/bin/
mv mongo mongo-backup
mv mongod mongod-backup
ln -s /usr/bin/mongo
ln -s /usr/bin/mongod
```

The error doesn't appear anymore, but the "initializing mongo database" step that follows might just hang.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Didn't have the hanging issue. I have the [latest mongo](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer: mongo and mongod from ~/.meteor/tools/latest/mongodb/bin are compiled with glibstc++ ~.15 and centos 6.4 has problems with it.

Replaced those two files with the files from /usr/bin and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're seeing this in prod? Try deleting .meteor\local\db*.lock, and if that doesn't work wipe the db by using meteor reset at the console.

If that still doesn't work, reply with your exact system specs, filesystem used, mongo binary used on prod, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in mongod binary. It is dynamically linked against glibc and libstdc++ of newer versions than the ones found in your system.

It was fixed yesterday (sep 23 2013) in trunk and will work on next versions of Meteor. Tested to work on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem. Find .meteor and .meteorite (if you using it) at you home directory (direcory of user which start meteor) and remove it. If you use meteorite - update it too:

```
npm install -g meteorite
```

After that create new project and remove all files but except .meteor and copy files of your project. Add all needs packages with 'meteor add' and 'meteorite add'. Try to start.

Comment: Sorry! Didn't work for me. I have uninstalled meteor meteorite and reinstalled them. When I create new project I have the same error. I think it's something with the permissions for mongo, error code 1 doesn't exist by the way.

Comment: Didn't work for me either on Ubuntu. And yes, [exit code 1 isn't documented](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/exit-codes/).